# how to check if a button that has been clicked has a class javascript (closed)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of buttons and each time one has been clicked I want to check if the one that has been clicked has a certain class name. I have looped over the button and then said if the button contains a class but this doesn't work.

Comment: If this is resolved, you can press the checkmark next to an answer to mark the post as "resolved". No need to add "(closed)" to your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to the buttons to listen for the "click" event.

```js
const helpBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.helpBtn');

for (let h = 0; h < helpBtn.length; h++) {
  helpBtn[h].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (helpBtn[h].classList.contains('doesHelp')) {
      console.log('Helped')
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="helpBtn doesHelp">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn doesHelp">Help</button>
```

Comment: that was in my code, forgot to add it

Comment: @CodeLover does this solution do what you want? If not, please edit your question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you wrote helpBtn[i] instead of helpBtn[h]:

```
helpBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
```

and i doesn't exist.